# Multiple dispatch calls from component react/redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I don't really know why I can't get this to work. All the evidence talks against it...This is the situation:

I have a grid of data and a search panel. When the search panel is changed the searchparams are updated and used for updating the data grid.

The thing which triggers the chain is when the user changes the search panel. In my component i handle search panel changes with this:

```
  getPhotos(key, value) {
    const change = [{ key: key, value: value},{ key: 'page', value: 1}]
    this.props.dispatch(updateSearchParams(change))

    console.log('payload.searchParams', this.props.searchParams);

    this.props.dispatch(
      getPhotos(
        { context:this.props.params.context,
          searchParams: this.props.searchParams }
      )
    );
  }
```

Thus two dispatch calls to action creators form the component. The problem is that the searchparams are not updated in time for the getPhotos call, so the grid is not updated accordingly.

I thought that dispatch calls were synchronous - thus one after the other. I guess that it is the round trip from the component, to the action creator, to the store and reducer which is "screwing" it up.
The first call does not involve any asynchronous calls.

What is the "right" way of doing this? Please be specific about what goes in the component, the action creator and the reducer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had it wrong from the beginning.

The searchparams should not go into the store. I can handle the in the component alone - in the state of the component. 
This the simplifies and eliminates the problem I described above.

Of cause there could be a situation where the searchparams needed to be available for other components. In that case I would go for @CodinCat answer above with the thunk. It works, i managed to implement it before my realisation.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`dispatch` is synchronous (unless you are using some middleware like redux-thunk). But after `this.props.dispatch(updateSearchParams(change))`
, your component needs to be updated (a re-render) or the `this.props.searchParams` is still the old one.

You can write `this.props.dispatch(getPhotos(...))` in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`, so you can access  the new props (`nextProps`)

---

If you are using redux-thunk and two actions `updateSearchParams` and `getPhotos` are always bind together, you can create another aggregated action creator for them.

```
const updateSearchParams = change => dispatch => {
  // return a promise here
  // or use callback style etc. whatever you prefered
}

const updateSearchParamsAndGetPhotos = (change, context) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(updateSearchParams(change))
    .then(res => {
      dispatch(getPhotos({
        context,
        searchParams: res.data.searchParams
      }))
    })
}
```

So now after dispatching a single action, your component should receive the new photos.